# How can i find maximum value in java

Tags: java

```
    try {
        ResultSet r = JDBC.getdata("SELECT MAX(TransactionID) from transaction");
        while (r.next()) {
            int l = r.getInt(1);

            int inid = l + 1;
            lbNewTransactionID.setText(new Integer(inid).toString());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I use this can't generate more than 10 numbers

Comment: Don't generate sequence numbers that way. That does not work in the face of concurrency. Use the sequence/autoincrement features of your database.

Comment: more than 10 numbers ? What happens after that?

Comment: So what is the last value of `l` in your database? I suspect last value is 90, so you're getting as `91`

Comment: No it doesn't work it print like this 91 , 92, 93 , 94 , 95 , 96 , 97 , 98 , 99, 100 , 100 , 100 ,100 ,100 .......... Like this. Last number can't guess

Comment: multithreading app?

Comment: So you have database with ID starting from 1 to 100++? and the problem is that when you print, after 10 it jumps to 91 and then when it reach 100, it repeats 100, 100, 100?

Comment: it repeats 100, 100, 100 ................